# Python List of Dictionaries to new Dictionary or List

Tags: python, dictionary

Pardon the noob question, I am new to Python.

I am working with a list of dictionaries:

```
dataset = [
    {'id':1,'dateCollected':'2021-03-02','orders':7},
    {'id':2,'dateCollected':'2021-03-03','orders':8},
]
```

.... this goes on for 50 records ....

I would like to a make a for loop that iterates through every dictionary in the list and adds certain key-value pairs to a new dictionary.

For Example:

```
match_history_data = {}

for i in dataset:
    match_history_data['DateCollected'] = i['dateCollected']
    match_history_data['Orders'] = i['orders']

print(match_history_data)
```

results in:

```
{'DateCollected': '2021-03-03', 'Orders': 8}
```

I would like the result to be:

```
{'DateCollected':'2021-03-02','Orders':7},
{'DateCollected':'2021-03-03','Orders':8}
```

This works how I want it to, but only for the first iteration in the for loop. How do I get around this so that it goes thru all the records in 'dataset', and creates the new list or dictionary?

Comment: What you have and what you want is basically the same, just the keys are capitalised and the `id` key is missing…!?

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a new dictionary, `match_history_data` and then just setting the same entries `'DateCollected'` and `'Orders'` over and over again. Each iteration of your for loop is just overwriting the same entries.

What you want is a list of new dictionaries:

```
match_history_data = []

for item in dataset:
    match_history_data.append(
            {"DateCollected" : item["dateCollected"],
             "Orders" : item["orders"]})
```

You can achieve this in a neater fashion using a list comprehension:

```
match_history_data = [{"DateCollected" : item["dateCollected"], "Orders" : item["orders"]} for item in dataset]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: You should also beware that this new list is almost identical to what you started with, making it a bit pointless and a waste of memory.

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
match_history_data = [{"DateCollected":x["dateCollected"], "Orders":x["orders"]} for x in dataset]
```

Comment: Nice. three more or less identical answers in same second.

Answer (score 0):

What you have right now overwrites a single dictionary as your loop through the original list of dictionaries, since keys are unique in dictionaries. What you need to is another list to which you can append the new dictionaries during each iteration to a separate list.

For example

```
new_list = []

for i in dataset:
    match_history_data = {}
    match_history_data['DateCollected'] = i['dateCollected']
    match_history_data['Orders'] = i['orders']
    new_list.append(match_history_data)
```

If you don't want to preserve the original list, you can simply drop the `id` key in each dictionary.